# Truncate table using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to truncate table using asp.net Entity Framework.

```
EPManagerEntities db;
// EPManagerEntities is my database class name
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Logs");
```

it show error like this

Table 'manager.logs' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the user for your connection has a default schema of 'manager' but the table you're trying to truncate is in a different schema.  Try using a two part name `[schema].Logs`.

Also, remember that `TRUNCATE` is technically a DDL statement so the user needs rights to alter the table.